# sizeof typedef pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct, typedef, sizeof

I have a struct that defined like that:

```
typedef struct my_struct
{
    int numbers[10];
}
*my_struct;
```

Is there a way to find out its size?

```
sizeof(my_struct);// return size of a pointer
```

Comment: `sizeof(*my_struct)`; `sizeof(struct my_struct)`.  See also the question [Is it a good idea to typedef pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers) — spoiler alert: the short answer is 'No' (unless they're function pointers, perhaps).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Err... did you test that? `my_struct` is a type, not a variable.

Comment: @KerrekSB: No.  The `sizeof(*my_struct)` version doesn't work — period (well, not unless you've gone shooting yourself in the foot with `my_struct my_struct = NULL;` or something similarly bizarre).  My bad!  I should be abed a couple of hours ago — it's a sloppy excuse, but it'll have to do.

Comment: sizeof(struct my_struct) worked for me, thank you Jonathan Leffler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The struct type itself is spelled with `struct`, so you can say:

```
sizeof (struct my_struct)
```

This would not work if you hadn't also given your struct a name, which would have been possible:

```
typedef struct { int numbers[10]; } * foo;  /* struct type has no name */
foo p = malloc(1000);
p->numbers[3] = 81;
```

I'd say all of this is poor code that is needlessly terse for no reason. I would just keep all the names unique, and name everything, and not alias pointers, for that matter. For example:

```
typedef struct my_struct_s my_struct;

my_struct * create_my_struct(void);
void destroy_my_struct(my_struct * p);

struct my_struct_s
{
    int numbers[10];
};
```

Everything has a unique name, the typedef is separate from the struct definition, and pointers are explicit.

Comment: Curious — with the tagless pointer `typedef`, there isn't a way to find the size of the structure unless you have a variable you can reference.  Just another reason not to typedef pointers — as if you really needed another.  It also means there's no way to create a direct instance of the type — you can only create the pointer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Yes, it's a totally silly thing to write.

Comment: I've added another [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43311191/) to [Is it a good idea to typedef pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers) that cross-references this question and discusses `typedef struct { …details… } *Information;` and its ramifications.